# Centering text or an image in a navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be able to center some text or image in a navbar, and this is how I'm doing it.

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-center navbar-text">
   <p><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/50/50'></p>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However it's only centered when the width is less than 768px. I think this has something to do with the responsiveness. How do I fix it so that it's centered in all widths?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float that is applied by `.navbar-text` above that width:

```
.navbar-text {
    float:none;
}
```

or simply remove the `navbar-text` class from your div:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-center">
      <p>
        <img src='http://placekitten.com/g/50/50'>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple. If we look at the [Bootstrap source code](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css), we can see with min width 768px it's floated to the left.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-text {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
```

The answer is to remove the float.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px)
{
    .navbar-text
    {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="text-center navbar-text">
            <p><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/50/50'></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```